# Pre-signup Cognito trigger

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a Lambda and trigger it from Cognito Pre-Sign-up trigger. The lambda should keep the signup works as it is, but it should Disable the users straight after they are created in Cognito !!

The code that disable the user works fine, but the problem is that I can't let the user be created first then to be disabled!!!

In the following code I have an error from the Disableuser function saying that "user doesn't exist"!!

PS: I don't need the autoconfirm user to be true or false, I just need the user to exist in Cognito with a Disable status!

Help please! I have been stuck on this for three days now !!

Thank you

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Confirm the user
    
        event.response.autoConfirmUser = false;
       
    
    // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyEmail = false;
        event.request.userAttributes.adminDisableUser= false;
        console.log('---------trying-222--------'+ event.request.userAttributes.adminDisableUser)
        console.log('event.response= '+ JSON.stringify(event.response));
    }
    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);

    /////Disable user code !!
    
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  
  var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'eu-west-1'
});
var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'Cognito UserPooool', /* required */
    Username: event.request.userAttributes.email /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDisableUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log('data inside disabled= '+data); 
    // context.done(data, null)
  callback(err, data)//successful response
});
   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Users will not exist in Cognito when the pre-signup trigger is invoked. You should move the disable user code into a post-confirm trigger.